# Получить User id текущего авторизированного пользователя

Tags: laravel

подскажите при обычной авторизации получаю `Auth::user()->id` через фасад `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth`, а как получить `user id` текущего пользователя используя `api Laravel Pasport` ?

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно выбрать соответсвующий `guard`

```
auth()->guard('api')->user()->getKey()
```